# VBscript run cmd and wait for output

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to read a user's PKI card data with Certutil and dump the data to a text file.  The idea is to put this as part of a login script to gather some data on user's with expiring certificates.

Here is my code section:

```
set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strcommand = "cmd /c certutil -scinfo -silent > " & StrPath
oShell.Run strcommand, true
```

it seems to work, dumping the cert data to a text file (strpath variable), but once I add more lines to the script it never waits for the command window to finish.  It just closes in a fraction of a second or so.  I know it takes aobut 7 seconds to read the PKI Card.  I've tried sleep as well as a do/while loop and nothing seems to allow the command window run its course.  I've also tried the various intwindowstyle options listed [here.](http://ss64.com/vb/run.html)

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

`oShell.Run strcommand, ,true` should work.  The second argument is the `intWindowStyle` argument, not `bWaitOnReturn`. You could also use

oShell.Run strcommand, bWaitOnReturn := true

If this doesn't work, you could try to use the [Exec Method](http://www.vbsedit.com/html/5593b353-ef4b-4c99-8ae1-f963bac48929.asp) . The documentation that this link leads to has a nice example of using a loop with `sleep` that runs until the process finishes.

Comment: That seems to work when I explicitly define the piped output for Certutil.  When I try to enter a variable in there it's back to ending the command prompt quickly...Any ideas?  Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("cmd /c certutil -scinfo -silent > " & StrPath)